# How to avoid long delay before finally getting "40001 could not serialize access due to concurrent update"

Tags: postgresql, performance, transactions, timeout, rollback

We have a Postgres 12 system running one master master and two async hot-standby replica servers and we use SERIALIZABLE transactions. All the database servers have very fast SSD storage for Postgres and 64 GB of RAM. Clients connect directly to master server if they cannot accept delayed data for a transaction. Read-only clients that accept data up to 5 seconds old use the replica servers for querying data. Read-only clients use REPEATABLE READ transactions.

I'm aware that because we use SERIALIZABLE transactions Postgres might give us false positive matches and force us to repeat transactions. This is fine and expected.

However, the problem I'm seeing is that **randomly a single line INSERT or UPDATE query stalls for a very long time**. As an example, one error case was as follows (speaking directly to master to allow modifying table data):

A simple single row insert

```
insert into restservices (id, parent_id, ...) values ('...', '...', ...);
```

stalled for 74.62 seconds before finally emitting error

```
ERROR 40001 could not serialize access due to concurrent update
```

with error context

```
SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."restservices" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x"
```

We log all queries exceeding 40 ms so I know this kind of stall is rare. Like maybe a couple of queries a day. We average around 200-400 transactions per second during normal load with 5-40 queries per transaction.

After finally getting the above error, the client code automatically released two savepoints, rolled back the transaction and disconnected from database (this cleanup took 2 ms total). It then reconnected to database 2 ms later and replayed the whole transaction from the start and finished in 66 ms including the time to connect to the database. So I think this is not about performance of the client or the master server as a whole. The expected transaction time is between 5-90 ms depending on transaction.

**Is there some PostgreSQL connection or master configuration setting that I can use to make PostgreSQL to return the error 40001 faster even if it caused more transactions to be rolled back?** Does anybody know if setting

```
set local statement_timeout='250'
```

within the transaction has dangerous side-effects? According to the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-client.html "Setting statement_timeout in postgresql.conf is not recommended because it would affect all sessions" but I could set the timeout only for transactions by this client that's able to automatically retry the transaction very fast.

Is there anything else to try?

Comment: Some slow non-interactive background tasks modify the same database with READ COMMITTED isolation level. Could that be the reason for **stalling** SERIALIZABLE transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like someone had the parent row to the one you were trying to insert locked.  PostgreSQL doesn't know what to do about that until the lock is released, so it blocks.  If you failed rather than blocking, and upon failure retried the exact same thing, the same parent row would (most likely) still be locked and so would just fail again, and you would busy-wait.  Busy-waiting is not good, so blocking rather than failing is generally a good thing here.  It blocks and then unblocks only to fail, but once it does fail a retry should succeed.

An obvious exception to blocking-better-than-failing being if when you retry, you can pick a different parent row to retry with, if that make sense in your context.  In this case, maybe the best thing to do is explicitly lock the parent row with NOWAIT before attempting the insert.  That way you can perhaps deal with failures in a more nuanced way.

If you must retry with the same parent_id, then I think the only real solution is to figure out who is holding the parent row lock for so long, and fix that.  I don't think that setting statement_timeout would be hazardous, but it also wouldn't solve your problem, as you would probably just keep retrying until the lock on the offending row is released.  (Setting it on the other session, the one holding the lock, might be helpful, depending on what *that* session is doing while the lock is held.)

Comment: Do you have some reason to think that the `parent_id` is the reason for the stall? I didn't notice anything towards that in the log but perhaps I'm missing something. Other tables have foreign references to `id` field of this table, too. Is it possible that the cause is activity in some other table? I'm still trying to pinpoint the actual cause for the stall.

Comment: Do you know if using e.g. `set local statement_timeout='250'` would be safe? I'm willing to wait for a small time if it allows the transaction to complete without retry. I agree that busy-waiting is something that I definitely don't want. However, I'm willing to retry the transaction e.g. 4 times per second and fallback to alternative handling after waiting e.g. 1 second in total. Having the wait in PostgreSQL would avoid having stupid 250 ms sleep in the client code because if resource is released sooner, the client wouldn't know it can continue already.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen The statement from the error context indicated the check was being done on the same table as the parent INSERT was using.  I think that that indicates a self-referencing FK.  If you log all queries with duration 40ms, that should give you a good record of who is holding that lock, (but perhaps not why they are holding it for so long).  Turning on log_lock_waits should also give more info.

Comment: Since you are already catching and dealing with errors, setting local statement_timeout would be safe.  I think the reason they recommend against setting it in postgresql.conf is to avoid accidentally interfering with administrative/maintenance tasks.

Comment: Thanks for great info! I think the problem was caused by background indexing task running with `READ COMMITTED` isolation level that did `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` and didn't commit the transaction soon enough (it had transaction open while talking to Elasticsearch which timed out). The current guess for the actual root cause is that the parent_id of the newly added row were referencing row locked by `FOR UPDATE`. I think we're going to change the indexing algorithm to not require `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` at all.